# How can I change the size of the arrow on my swiperjs slider?

Tags: swiper.js

I already tried to change it by trying to use svg{transform: scale(0.5);} but it doesn't work, I also can't access the arrow class... NOTE: they are using the swiper through the CDN

```
<swiper-container class="mySwiper w-full h-full" navigation="true">
                <swiper-slide class="flex flex-col items-center gap-10">
                    <div class="w-72 h-40 relative bg-blue-400 overflow-hidden rounded-lg">
                        <img src="../images/section/img2-desktop.jpg" alt="" class="bg-contain w-full">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-20 text-left px-10">
                        <h2 class="text-lg">Algum texto</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, consequatur voluptatem</p>
                        <button>lei mais</button>
                    </div>
                </swiper-slide>
                <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
            </swiper-container>
```

I just want to reduce the size of the arrow